# Switching Wordpress Multi-site to HTTPS - redirection loop

Tags: wordpress, redirect, https, multisite

I am recovering a wordpress multi-site installation and switching it to https. The apache configuration is well done and wordpress can be accessed using ssl.

However, all links from wordpress are still referring to the non http version.

When I try to modify the `home` and `siteurl` variables in wp_options, Wordpress is creating a redirection loop.

From curl when getting /:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 26 Dec 2017 12:17:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.example.com/
```

Adding this does not affect anything.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

I tried:

- clearing cache
- clearing cookies
- disabling all extensions.
- checking apache's error logs.
- deleting .htaccess

But I am still unsuccessful.

Any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: Are you using SSL directly in Apache, or are you behind a reverse proxy (like nginx, or a commercial provider like Cloudflare)? Did you change the variables to point to https? Generally, internal links will not be automatically rewritten if they're in the DB, you should use a plugin to search & replace those.

Comment: Yes I am behind a custom nginx reverse proxy.

I have rewritten every instance of http://www.example.com to https://example.com in the database. Changing them does not affect most of the links. Only the "home" variable seems to do that but it is also the variable which produces the infinite loop.

Comment: The problem is indeed with the reverse proxy which actually does the HTTPS.

I added to wp-config.php the following:
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

And everything is working now, without rewriting the home variable.

The final solution is probably something on the nginx with:
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

Comment: That probably solved your problem, right? The reason is simple, WP could not determine that the request came via HTTPS, so it assumed it to be plain HTTP. As for the links: yes, dynamic links (menu items, links in archive pages to articles) will depend on home, links in post content are generally static and will be preserved as you entered them.